# By how much does debt exceed credit in major currencies?

Tags: currency, debt, credit

Fiat currency is created by issuing loans.

Assume 100 crowns (a non-specific currency) existed before the crown became a fiat currency.

Every time a new 100 crown loan is made, 100 crowns of credit and 105 crowns of debt are created.  (A 5% interest rate.)

Once more than twenty such loans have been created, the net number of crowns becomes negative.  Debt outnumbers credit.

Can these subsequent loans only be repaid (in full) by the credit from new loans?

Have all major fiat currencies gone past this point, and if so is it impossible for all debts to be repaid without an accelerating quantity of new loans being made?

Are there published figures for the quantities of credit and debt in major fiat currencies?